# WPF: How do I set the content of a Paragraph in Code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I've got a FlowDocument and assigned a name to one paragraph.

I want to edit the content of a paragraph (which is just one ordinary string btw.).

How to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(yourString));
flowDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

Comment: OK and how can I change the content (String) of an Inline?

Comment: flowDocument.Blocks is an enumerable collection, so you can use for example foreach statement to iterate over it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's it.
Please also look at this question if you don't mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781109/flowdocument-replace-section

Answer (score 1):

To change the text of an existing paragraph can be done this way. (Individual formattings of the paragraph get lost!)

```
// myParagraph is the paragraph with the old text

while (myParagraph.Inlines.Count > 0)
    myParagraph.Inlines.Remove(myParagraph.Inlines.ElementAt(0));

myParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("new text"));
```