# FlowDocument replace Section?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, flowdocument

I have a FlowDocument with two Sections.
One is named 'Inhalt'.

Trying to replace it with another Section doesn't seem to work:

```
        InfoBoxAuditorium.Inhalt = InfoBoxAuditorium.Resources["DokumentWohnzimmer"] as Section;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Inhalt` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the records. I solved this by surrounding the FlowDocument with another Grid.
The first row contains the stuff I don't want to be replaced.
Easy but it does its job.